# Use a sql file to populate data in ruby

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a sql file and i want to use it to populate the psql in RoR.
the  psql ___ < ______.sql is not working ? Can you please guide me on how to use this sql file and use it

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pg_restore` like this:

```
rails db:drop
rails db:create
pg_restore -d db_name file_name.sql
```